# Kendo Grid DateTime Format

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using kendo grid. my problem is  if user dont enter a "Sonlandigi Tarih" grid show "null".but I dont want to show "null" in grid. I want to like a string.Empty. how can I solve it ? how can I write if else in ClientTemplate ?

[image]

my grid code:

```
columns.Bound(c => c.SonlandigiTarih).ClientTemplate("# if(SonlandigiTarih!=null) {# <div title='#=SonlandigiTarih#'>#=SonlandigiTarih#</div>#}#").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "hidden-xs" }).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "hidden-xs" }).ClientTemplate("#= kendo.toString(SonlandigiTarih, \"dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm\") #");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
columns.Bound(c => c.SonlandigiTarih).ClientTemplate("#: (SonlandigiTarih ? kendo.toString(SonlandigiTarih, 'dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm') : '') #").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "hidden-xs" }).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "hidden-xs" });
```